# Explanation on Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following Java program:

```
public class A extends Thread {
    int count;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            count++;
    }

    public static void main(String...strings){
        A obj = new A();
        obj.start();
        System.out.println("The value of count is " + obj.count);
    }
}
```

When running this program the output is: `The value of count is 0` (and the program stays running). As far as my understanding with thread it should run in an infinite loop and never print 0. Could anyone help me understanding the nature of this program.

Comment: How about adding a loop to the print? there is no guarantee that the Thread that increases the count would be excuted before the sysout. However if you add a loop there you may see the count increasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread starts at about the same time as the System.out.println runs, and since the thread is background, the println does not wait for it to run, and so you are seeing the initial value of count.

Also as an aside, the count variable should be declared volatile to ensure that the main thread [sees changes to the variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) made in the loop thread.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, I do not know why I was thinking that Main is calling run and it would not run system.out until the control return.

Comment: @Ashish: control would then have *never* returned to main.

Comment: Yes Sir I see your point. Sorry for such a silly mistake and thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The "thread" isn't doing the print, your main is. What were you expecting to happen?

You should also use some kind of protection so both threads can safely access the variable.

Comment: No "protection" is really needed here, since only one thread is modifying count. There is no chance for a race or a lock to occur with the current code. The variable should be declared volatile though to prevent the main thread from making a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the System.out call only run once?

I would put the System.out.println call inside the while loop.

Its probably better to use a getter/setter method for `count` and make sure only one or the other can access the variable at any given time.